# How to show a window overlay over the accessibility menu in android 10?

Tags: android, kotlin, overlay, android-overlay, system-alert-window

I have done some code which is working fine everywhere except settings app -> accessibility menu or device admin apps menu

I need to display overlay in settings -> accessibility and device admin apps menu

I have a application where i see this type of overlay you can see below image

[First image from settings app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA6hr.png)

[Second image from settings app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUs89.png)

> You can see above second image when i open -> **device admin app** -> then my app overlay got hidden but another app overlay is still visible I don't know why?

Please help me guys to fix this issue??

**AndridManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />

    <application
        .....
         .....
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".OverlayService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.PixelFormat
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.view.*


class OverlayService : Service() {

    private var windowManager: WindowManager? = null
    private var view: View? = null

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val layoutParamsType: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
        }

        val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams().apply {
            width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            type = layoutParamsType
            flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
            format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        }
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER or Gravity.START

        val inflater = getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_view, null)

        windowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        windowManager!!.addView(view, params)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (view != null) {
            windowManager!!.removeView(view)
            view = null
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                startService(Intent(this, OverlayService::class.java))
            } else {
                startManageDrawOverlaysPermission()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CODE_DRAW_OVERLAY_PERMISSION -> {
                if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                    startService(Intent(this, OverlayService::class.java))
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission is not granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startManageDrawOverlaysPermission() {
        Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, "package:${packageName}".toUri()).apply {
            startActivityForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_DRAW_OVERLAY_PERMISSION)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_DRAW_OVERLAY_PERMISSION = 5
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show !"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**overlay_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="#00897B"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Overlay Example View"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```